# Is it possible to use the LaTeX citation command "\cite{key}" when using knitr in Rstudio?

Tags: citing, markdown, rstudio

I've been looking for a way to use the `\cite{AuthorYear}` or `\citep{AuthorYear}` command on my markdown document on Rstudio instead of the `[@AuthorYear]`, but have not managed to find any solutions here. Does anyone have a tip or resource to look for?

The reason for this is that I need to render word files for others to edit during the review process, but I would like to produce the final document with a LaTeX template for journal submission. Having the citations in this format would make for a much faster document transfer.

So far I have tried this in my markdown header to no avail:

```
 ---
title: "BEACH Formalisms"
header-includes: 
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{natbib}
output:
  pdf_document: default
  word_document: default
bibliography: library.bib
---
```

Test:

```
My citation text \citep{AuthorYear1, AuthorYear2}.
```

The result:

> My citation text (??).

Namely: citations brackets do appear in the text, but the authors are just questions marks.

Do I need to declare a citation format or something else in the header? If so, appreciate your help!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "use a different approach" solution. As DG' mentiones one cannot use LaTeX commands in Word output. However, one can use standard RMarkdown syntax and let `pandoc` handle the translation to LaTeX:

````
---
title: "BEACH Formalisms"
header-includes: \usepackage{mathtools}
output:
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
    keep_tex: yes
  word_document: default
bibliography: packages.bib
---

```{r include=FALSE}
# automatically create a bib database for R packages
knitr::write_bib(c(
  .packages(), 'knitr', 'rmarkdown'
), 'packages.bib')
```


My citation text [@R-knitr; @R-base].
````

With this you will have a `.tex` file corresponding to your `.Rmd` file which you can base your journal submission on.

Comment: In pandoc you have to use semicola to seperate citations: `[@R-knitr; @R-base]`  --> `\citep{R-knitr, R-base}`

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me for PDF output

````
---
title: "BEACH Formalisms"
header-includes: 
  \usepackage{mathtools}
output:
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
  word_document: default
bibliography: packages.bib
---

```{r include=FALSE}
# automatically create a bib database for R packages
knitr::write_bib(c(
  .packages(), 'knitr', 'rmarkdown'
), 'packages.bib')
```

My citation text \citep{R-knitr, R-base}.
````

Defining `natbib` as `citation_package` seems to be the key.

Comment: Hi @Ralf Stubner, thanks for the response! That did it for the pdf render. Unfortunately the citation disappears when rendering for the beloved Word.doc. Any idea how to make it work on both? 

Thanks! 
PS. If no other answers come by, I'll accept the answer as it gets me closer to were I am heading!

Comment: The docx-writer can't use `natbib` so you can't use `\citep` for word export.